# codeigniter get correct values of checked checkboxs

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

In one of my forms i have the following code, that lists the images of a folder, and add to them checkboxs, which values are the names of the images, so that i can check the images i want:

```
<?php
$imgdir = 'upload/'; //Pick your folder
$allowed_types = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif'); //Allowed types of files
$dimg = opendir($imgdir);//Open directory
while($imgfile = readdir($dimg))
{

if( in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-3)),$allowed_types) OR
in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-4)),$allowed_types) )
/*If the file is an image add it to the array*/
{$a_img[] = $imgfile;}
}
echo "<ul>";

$totimg = count($a_img);  //The total count of all the images
//Echo out the images and their paths incased in an li.
for($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++){echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check_imagens[]' value='" .$a_img[$x]."'/><img height='50' width='50' src='http://localhost/code/" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "' />"; echo $a_img[$x];} 
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Now, in the model of my class, i'm trying to get the values of the checkbox's i checked through the following code:

```
$data_imagens = array(
    'imagens_selected' => $this->input->post('check_imagens')
);

var_dump($data_imagens);
```

However, i guess i'm getting more than the value, or at least i have some problem because if i next do a search in my database to find the ids of the images checked:

```
    foreach ($data_imagens as $value) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_imagem FROM imagens where nome_imagem='".$value."';");
}


            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
       echo $row['id_imagem'];
    }
```

Can anyone please point me what am i doing wrong? Thank you!

SOLVED:

I was using wrong the foreach to get the values of the check_images array. Instead of:

```
    foreach ($data_imagens as $value) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_imagem FROM imagens where nome_imagem='".$value."';");
}


            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
       echo $row['id_imagem'];
    }
```

What i need was:

```
    foreach ($this->input->post('check_imagens') as $key => $value)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_imagem FROM imagens where nome_imagem='".$value."';");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      echo $row->id_imagem;
   }
    $imagens_selected[$key]=$value;
    echo $imagens_selected[$key];
}
```

Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: in your loop you are doing this:echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check_imagens[]'....... instead of this: echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check_imagens'

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Like my answer says. :)

Comment: heheh @Madbreaks - but I was faster :)

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Look again ;)

Comment: @Madbreaks, I should downvote you -___- :)

Comment: @user1511579 - you said: because if i next do a search in my database to find the ids of the images checked: -- but you didn't continue. might you say anything in addition!?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan it's solved. Check my main post updated. Thank you for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need multiple values, don't use array-like notation for the `<input>` name:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check_imagens[]' value='"...
                                         ^^^^
```

Just change that to `check_imagens`.

Comment: But i can check more than one checkbox, which means more than one image selected, shouldn't i use an array?

Comment: But where am i treating my input as a single value? Maybe that's my problem

Comment: I misunderstood your question.  Can you please explain what the issue is?  The last thing you say is, *"if i next do a search in my database to find the ids of the images checked"*

Comment: Ok, here goes.
First i have a for in my view that list all the images i have in a folder and associate a checkbox to each of them where the value is the name of the image.
What i pretend is in my model, through 'imagens_selected' => $this->input->post('check_imagens'), get the values of the checkbox's selected, to after that made some select's to my database with the values i got from the checkboxs selected.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Please update your question.  *You are not telling us what is going wrong, or what you are seeing that is unexpected*.

Comment: My problem is in the last piece of code i posted in the main post. I don't know if i can do that, i mean, if in the foreach ($data_imagens as $value), the $value are getting only the values of the checkboxs or something else.

Comment: **UPDATE YOUR QUESTION**..stop posting in the comments, please.  Update your question with the relevant information so that everyone reading it can understand what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, i will do it. I have to leave now to solve a problem, as soon as i get back i will update

Comment: i made your answer the correct one. I solved the problem when i return. Check my main post to see what i was doing wrong. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Since you solved your own problem, you don't need to mark my answer correct, you could instead just up-vote it ("thanks for the help").  Cheers